# Whether $\varepsilon$ can be a function of $x$ in $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof of limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Isn't $ε(x)$ allowed? Why can't $ε(x)$ be a function of $x$, and restrict $f(x)$ within the range of $(L-ε(x), L+ε(x))$? It seems to be an assumption by default but nobody says it.

Example:

Prove f(x)>0 and limf(x)=L imply L>=0.

Proof: As L is the limit of f(x), for any ε>0, there exists 0<|x−a|<δ, s.t. |f(x)−L|<ϵ. Take ε=f(x)>0, and there exists 0<|x−a|<δ, s.t. |f(x)−L|<=ϵ. Then from f(x)<= L+ε, L>=0. Proof done.

Comment: Why would you want $\varepsilon$ to be a function of $x$? Can you write down the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ *definition* of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$? Then, at some point, you may see that one cannot define $\varepsilon$ as a function of $x$.

Comment: I wrote it down, by just replacing ε with ε(x), only to find no clear violation of anything

Comment: The definition says the following: for **any** given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$, such that whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. At what point do you think it is OK to replacing $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon(x)$? And what would be your definition of $\epsilon(x)$?

Comment: There's nowhere showing it's not ok either, is there

Comment: Of course it is not OK. If you claim/think that you could do it, do you have an example? One can of course write whatever one likes, however, every mathematical symbol has its precise definition and meaning, what would that be for your $\epsilon(x)$?

Comment: Once you write down your version of the definition using the symbol $\epsilon(x)$ in your post (which you should), you would see what goes wrong.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 2} x^2\ne 4$.  Pf: If $\lim_{x\to 2} x^2=4$ thene for every $\epsilon >0$ there would be a $\delta$ where $|x-2|<\delta\implies |f(x)-4|< 0$.  Let $\epsilon(x) =|x^2-4|$.  Then  there can not exist a $\delta$ where $|x-2|<\delta\implies|f(x)-4|<\epsilon(x)$ as $\epsilon(x)=|f(x)-4|$ always.

Comment: Example added in the question

Comment: @feynman: the statement in your example is not complete and is not necessarily true: (1)$f(x)>0$ alone does not imply that the limit exists (and what is $\lim_{x\to?}$??) (2) Even you assume that $f(x)>0$ **and** the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ exists, one cannot say that $L>0$. Think about $f(x)=x^2$ and $a=0$.

Comment: If $f(x) >0$ and $\lim f(x) =L$ then $L <0$.  Pf: Assume $L \ge 0$.  Let $\epsilon =f(x)+\frac 1{1000}L> 0$.  So $|f(x)-L| < f(x)+\frac 1{1000}L$.  If $f(x) \ge L$ then $f(x) -L <f(x)+\frac 1{1000}L$ and $0<-\frac {999}{1000} L$ so $L < 0$  if $f(x)< L$ then let $\epsilon = L-f(x)$.  Then $|f(x)-L| < L-(fx) = |f(x)-L|$ so $0< 0$.  That's a contradiction.  So $L < 0$.

Comment: You *cant* just make things up by fiat.  That you insist on doing so and refuse to even recognize that you are doing so is disturbing.  If we allow $\epsilon$ to be a function simply botches the entire definition up so that it is utterly meaningless.  That really should be obvious.  We can define $\epsilon(x)= 2 |f(x)-L|$ to make is to taht *everything* are limits.  Ore we can define $\epsilon(x)=0.5|f(x)-L|$ soo that *nothing* is a limit.

Comment: example modified

Comment: The example is still gibberish.  If $\lim f(x)=L$ you *don't* have a value of $x$ so you *don't* have a $\delta >|x-a|$ because you dont have an $x$ in the first place.  You have a $\delta$ so that *if* you have an $x$ so that $|x-a|<\delta$ then it will follow that that $|f(x)-L|$ *will* be less than $\epsilon$.  But like we've be trying and trying to tell you $\epsilon$ is *NOT* a function. After all $|f(x)-L|$ *itself* is a function and you can't ever have $|f(x)-L| <|f(x)-L|$.  This should be obvious as you are taking $\epsilon(x)=f(x)$.  This is tantamount to saying $f(x)$ can ...

Comment: ... anything we want because I changed the very definitions of math just so we can prove what we want.  If we could do this I could claim $\epsilon(0) = \frac {f(x)}{gazillion}$ and claim that all functions are tiny.  This just makes *zero* sense.

Comment: @fleablood Your comment is gibberish. By writing limf(x)=L, x->a is simply omitted by default

Comment: To correct you language *and* to continue your idea that $\epsilon$ may be a function your wording should be: If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta$ so that when you choose an $|x-a|<\delta$ it will follow that $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.  If you let $\epsilon(x)=f(x)$ you there is a delta so that $|x-a|<$ means $|f(x)-L|<f(x)$. If we ignore absolute values that means $L>0$.  Now it should be obvious that proof is garbage.  If $\epsilon$ can be a function we can set it to *anything* and get garbage results. And *nothing* you did involved anything *about* $f(x)$.

Comment: And ***again*** If you definnition is correct then.  If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$, $f$ is not constant, and $\epsilon(x) =|f(x)-L|$ then there is a $\delta$ so that if $|x-a|<\delta$ would imply that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon = |f(x)-L|$.  That is *impossible*.  So no such $\delta$ exists.  So $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ is impossible.  We've been telling you for over a day that $\epsilon$ can *NOT* be a function and we've told you why it can't be.  I don't know why you are refusing to listen.

Comment: Way to go! The above example is encouraging. But what's the philosophy behind ϵ forbidden to be a function of x? What if ϵ(x) isn't chosen as |f(x)−L|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model the function as kicking a football.

If it's well-behaved, you can find a small range of angles to swing your foot in, and you'll score a goal. Having ε as a function of x would be like moving the goalposts as you go to kick.

Comment: That's a great answer. However does it suffice to disprove ε(x)?

Comment: No, but it goes some way to explaining why it tells you nothing about the function if you allow it. You'll never know how good at football you are if you keep moving the goalposts.

Answer (score 11):

An arbitrary $\varepsilon$ is *given* to you, and you have *no* control over it (you know it's positive, and that's it). You have to *find* a $\delta$ that works for the $\varepsilon$ you have. And the $\delta$ can be a function of the point you're taking the limit at, and a function of $\varepsilon$, but it is $\delta$ that restricts what possible values $x$ can have, so $\delta$ can't be a function of $x$.

Comment: It is true that there's no control over what ε to take. But if ε is taken to be ε(x) in a proof, is it allowed?

Comment: @feynman No. That's just completely counter to the order in which things happen. You start with a point where you're taking a limit, and a value you think the limit has. You're given an arbitrary $\varepsilon$. Given those three things, you try to find a $\delta$, and only _then_ does $x$ enter the picture.

Comment: That still doesn't anwer why ε can't be a function of x

Comment: The facts that δ can't be a function of x, and ε can be a function of δ, don't mean ε can't be a function of x.

Comment: @feynman It's more fundamental than that. $\varepsilon$ is _given_ to you. You can't control what it is. You can't decide what it depends on and what it doesn't depend on. And even outside of your control it can't depend on $x$ in any way, as $x$ **doesn't exist** until after $\varepsilon$, and later $\delta$, have been established.

Comment: ε being given to you doesn't mean you can't control it at all. You can take it to be greater or less than sth for example.

Comment: @feynman No, you can't. You can _pretend_ that $\varepsilon$ is, say, at most $1$, and work with that. Then you have to prove that if it happens to be greater than $1$, everything still works out. But you do not have any actual control over $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @feynman I won't do that. I don't get notified in chat, so it's somewhere where I will have to actively check for responses, compared to a comment thread where I will automatically see whenever there is a response. I know the site tends to suggest moving to chat when a discussion goes on long enough, but I _strongly_ prefer not to go in there.

Comment: example modified

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sell the truth of
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$$
to a customer you say: Name any tolerance $\epsilon>0$, e.g., $\epsilon:=10^{-6}$, and I guarantee that  $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ as soon as $x$ is near enough to $a$, e.g., it could be that $|x-a|\leq 10^{-4}$ suffices.

Note that in this argument the value of $\epsilon$ is not a constant (that might depend on $a$), but can be arbitrarily chosen by the customer. If your guarantee would work just for $\epsilon=0.01$ the graph of $f$ could still wiggle by $\pm0.01$ in the *tiniest* neighborhood of $x=a$. You don't want this for a proper limit.

Comment: What's the conclusion of this answer

Answer (score 3):

If functions were allowed then demonstrating a limit exists would not be showing restricting a span in the domain results in restrict a span in the range if the span in the range can be variable based on the $x$.

Consider $\epsilon(x) = \frac {|f(x) - L|}3$.

So if we define $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$ if for any $\epsilon(x) > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ so that $|x-c|<\delta$ will imply $|f(x)-L|< \epsilon$

Well, that will never happen if we define $\epsilon(x) = \frac {|f(x) - L|}3$.

So what's the point of making up a confusing definition for something that can never occur.

Limits dont exist.  I guess.

Comment: Example added in the question

Comment: Your proof is as valid as the following.  All bunnies are pink.  Pf:  By definition "pink" means "eats grass".  Bunnies need grass and die if they don't eat grass (why? because I wrote the book about bunnies and I included it in it).  And bunnies are alive, so they must eat grass.  Therefore all bunnies are pink..... You can't make up your definitions and then write a bunch of symbols down and assume they are true. How do you know $\lim f(x)$ exists at all.  By *your* definition it *CAN'T*.  And... oh, there's no point... but your examples is useless.

Comment: example modified

Answer (score 2):

To prove that the limit of $f$ at $x_0$ is $L$, i.e. to prove $$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L,$$ you must prove the following:

> For all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$, if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

In the statement above, it should be clear that the statement must be shown to be true for all $\epsilon$, that is $\epsilon$ is most certainly not a constant. In fact, it is an arbitrary value - you must prove that no matter what it is, the implication holds.

Of course, $\delta$ can depend on $\epsilon$. Note, however, as $x_0$ was selected even earlier, $\delta$ *can* depend on $x_0$ as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about ε not being a constant. ε is taken as a fixed constant at the start of a proof, and δ is calculated according to the ε afterwards. Then ε can be taken other values, but it's still taken as a constant each time.

Comment: @feynman Sure, at the start of a proof, $\epsilon$ is taken as a "fixed" value in that *you* are not allowed to change it. But it is not what I would call a constant. It is an unknown value. The very fact that $\epsilon$ can take any positive value is contrary to what "constant" means...

Comment: anyway, what's your answer to my original question

Comment: @feynman Your original question is malformed, as my answer should explain. Proving a limit equals something means proving a given statement *for every possible value of $\epsilon$*. The concept of $\epsilon(x)$ does not exist, because $\epsilon$ is a number, not a function.

Comment: Why can't ϵ(x) be a function of x, and restrict f(x) within the range of (L-ϵ(x), L+ϵ(x))?

Comment: @feynman $\epsilon$ is a number, not a function. Because that's what the definition of limit says it is. That's how we define limits. They are equal to something is some statement is true for every possible positive number $\epsilon$.

Comment: That would make the definition of a limit unnecessarily complicated, and there should be constraints on $\epsilon(x)$, such as lower and upper bounds, and continuity and blah blah, possibly leading to circular arguments.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There's still no strong evidence banning the possibility of ε(x), given those complexities

Comment: @feynman: but what's the benefit ? It is negative ! You don't create definitions "for fun".

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't know the benefit. That's a question I was asked which I can't disprove

Comment: @feynman: you could allow an $\epsilon(x)$. That would be a very poor idea.

Comment: Example added in the question

Comment: @feynman If we allow $\epsilon(x)$ to be a function, then every function $f$ is continuous, because we can always take $\epsilon(x)=|f(x)-L|+1$ and then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ is trivially true.

Comment: @5xum But in proving the limit exists, ϵ needs to be arbitrary. So one ϵ doesn't suffice.

Comment: example modified

Comment: @5xum But this must be true of every function so we'd have to be able to let $\epsilon(x) = 0.5|f(x)-L|$.  And $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon $ can *never* be true.  So limits *never* exist except for constant functions and *no* non-constant function is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

The $\varepsilon$ in the definition of limit is a constant and therefore it has to be independent of $x$.

The key is that your argument should work for all positive values of this $\varepsilon$ and your argument should treat $\varepsilon$ symbolically without assuming anything other than $\varepsilon>0$.

On the other hand if one wants to disprove a limit condition then it is necessary to pick some specific value of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: The premise is that the limit L was already proven to exist. Then is it possible to take ε(x)?

Comment: @feynman: in any case the $\epsilon $ has to be treated independent of $x$.